# select() socket call CPU consumption

Tags: sockets, select, cpu, sleep

If I have the following code with select call and suppose the socket fds are not ready for I/O for most of the time, will the thread take CPU or will it sleep and let the other thread do the job. Is select() a CPU intensive call?

```
while(1)
{
   select(maxfd, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Will the behaviour be same it the timeout = 0 (kind of polling ) instead of NULL.

Comment: How does select() resume after indefinite blocking? Who will notify the thread in which select was blocked?

Answer (score 2):

If the timeout value is NULL, select will block indefinitely until data is available on the sockets and file descriptors in rfds. However, as soon as data is available on any file descriptor in that set, the code you have will consume the entire CPU since you don't show any thing that suggests draining the data off the socket.  (The second call to select will return immediately indicating there is still data on the socket).

If you pass in a zero'd out timeval to select, it will be a non-blocking poll.  It's equivalent to calling send() or recv() with the MSG_DONTWAIT flag (but without data being copied).

Comment: Thanks for the info. While indefinite blocking, will the thread consume CPU?